# Why does this execution plan have Compute Scalars?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, execution-plan

I have a simple `SELECT` statement.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2014]
GO

SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
```

The execution plan has two `Compute Scalar`.

[image: Execution Plan showing Compute Scalars]
Why is this?  I was expecting to just get the `Index Scan` or maybe a `Table Scan`?

The first (rght-most) has

```
 [[AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].LineTotal] = Scalar Operator(isnull(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(19,4),[AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[UnitPrice] as [sod].[UnitPrice],0)*((1.0)-CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(19,4),[AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[UnitPriceDiscount] as [sod].[UnitPriceDiscount],0))*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(numeric(5,0),[AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[OrderQty] as [sod].[OrderQty],0),(0.000000)))
```

When second has:

```
[[sod].LineTotal] = Scalar Operator([AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail].[LineTotal] as [sod].[LineTotal])
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Compute Scalars are related to the computed field LineTotal. Script out the table, and you'll see that field defined as:

```
[LineTotal]  AS (isnull(([UnitPrice]*((1.0)-[UnitPriceDiscount]))*[OrderQty],(0.0))),
```

SQL Server has two operations to perform. It has to first run the calculation of:

```
[UnitPrice]*((1.0)-[UnitPriceDiscount]))*[OrderQty]
```

Then it has to check to see if that value is null, and if so, substitute 0.0.